# javafx - problems doing setText on MenuButton

Tags: javafx, fxml

So I have this code here:

```
// import statements are ommitted

public class HomePage implements Initializable{


@FXML
private volatile MenuButton fullUserName;

public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle)
{

}

public void loadHomePage(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    Parent HomePage = FXMLLoader.load(LoginScreen.class.getResource("HomePage.fxml"));

    Timer animTimer = new Timer();
    animTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        int i=0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (i<100) {
                primaryStage.setX(primaryStage.getX() - 4);
                primaryStage.setY(primaryStage.getY() - 1);
                primaryStage.setWidth(primaryStage.getWidth()+8.11);
                primaryStage.setHeight(primaryStage.getHeight()+3.19);
            } else {
                this.cancel();
            }
            i++;
        }

    }, 0, 10);

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10 * 101), ev -> {
        primaryStage.setResizable(true);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(HomePage));
        fullUserName.setText("User"); // Got NullPointerException at this line
    }));
    timeline.play();

}

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
        loadHomePage(primaryStage);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

HomePage.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="9.0" minWidth="16.0" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1280.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.HomePage">
<top>
  <GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="32.5" style="-fx-background-color: #aeccc9;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="11.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="27.5" />
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="11.5" />
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="10.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="15.0" />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    </rowConstraints>
     <children>
        <MenuButton fx:id="fullUserName" mnemonicParsing="false" GridPane.columnIndex="4">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Logout" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Exit" />
          </items>
           <graphic>
              <ImageView fitHeight="22.0" fitWidth="22.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                 <image>
                    <Image url="@Cool-50.png" />
                 </image>
              </ImageView>
           </graphic>
           <padding>
              <Insets bottom="-1.5" left="-1.5" right="-1.5" top="-1.5" />
           </padding>
        </MenuButton>
        <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Title" GridPane.columnIndex="3">
           <font>
              <Font name="Arial Rounded MT Bold" size="22.0" />
           </font>
        </Text>
     </children>
  </GridPane>
</top>
</BorderPane>
```

So as you can see, I got a `NullPointerException` when executing `fullUserName.setText("User");` which means that the "fullUserName" menu button is not initialized.

Is it possible for the program to wait until fullUserName (or any other FXML variables for that matter) has been initialized so that I can execute the statement?

Comment: You are mixing the `Application` and the controller. You are starting a controller like an `Application` therefore the injection here will not take place. When you load the FXML file `Parent HomePage = FXMLLoader.load(LoginScreen.class.getResource("HomePage.fxml"));` a separate instance of this class is created, where the injection is done. To avoid misunderstandings, [a good place to start](https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/connecting_scenebuilder_edited_fxml_to).

Comment: Also, use another `Timeline` instead of a `Timer` to animate the window. With the code as you have it, you are updating the UI from a background thread.